# async.eachSeries not working as expected with mongodb call in iterator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, series

I'm trying to insert an array in an ordered way into a mongodb database, for that i'm using async.eachSeries but the rows are not inserted in the order as they are in the array. Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/r01010010/af8eeb39023ce1cc04f6#file-series-js-L16

```
  var server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, safe: true});
  var db = new mongodb.Db('scjs', server);

  db.open(function(err, db) { if(err) throw err;


  async.eachSeries(

      // Collection
        mongo_provinces

      // Iterator
      , function(province, done){
          db.collection('provinces').insert(province, function(err, result) { if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);
              done();
          });
      }

      // Callback when the iteration is finished
      , function(err){ if(err) throw err;
          process.exit();
      }
  );


  });
```

Comment: I don't know `eachSeries`, but i do know `forEachSeries` which works perfect for me and will also serve your purpose well.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on the order of insertion here, but on the retrieval instead. If no ordering is specified, then the default query will return documents in the natural order. If you want to get results in specific order, apply sort parameter:

- Using sort: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort
- Natural order: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order